# Running .filter and .map synchronously

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, filter

Hello I am having an issue running this function wherein im trying to filter this an array of objects then afterwards im reorganizing by reassigning my id with the index of the .map The issue that occurs is that the .filter is not deleting/removing an items in the function. Here is my code as reference:
What do be the best solution of this. Any input would be helpful thank you.

```
 const removeData = (id) => {
        const del = idleData.filter(idle => id !== idle.id).map((item,index) => (
            {
                id: index, 
                days: item.day,
                comments: item.comments,
                cost: item.cost,
                reason: item.reason,
                portCallVoyageId: item.portCallVoyageId,
                changedBy: item.changedBy
            }
        ));
        setIdleData(del);
    }
```

Here is idleData and idle:

```
idleData = [{
  id: 0,
  cost: 10,
  days: 10,
  comments: 'comment 1',
  reason: "reason 1",
  changedBy: "user1"
}, {
  id: 1,
  cost: 20,
  days: 20,
  comments: 'comment 2',
  reason: "reason 2",
  changedBy: "user2"
}];

idle = 0;
```

Comment: Could you share the data of ```idleData``` array?

Comment: Can you provide a working example? This should be filtering out items where id matches the id of the idle object. We would need to see the data and how it is behaving.

Comment: idleData looks like this 
`[
    { id: 0, cost: 10, days: 10, comments: 'comment 1', reason: "reason 1", changedBy: "user1" },
    { id: 1, cost: 20, days: 20, comments: 'comment 2', reason: "reason 2", changedBy: "user2" }
];`

Comment: Is your `id` variable of the correct type? Is it definitely a number?

Comment: I also forgot I have a function that adds a new row here is the code ` const addRow = () => {
        setIdleData((previousState) => [...previousState, {id: idleData.length, cost: 0, days: 0, comments: '', portCallVoyageId:11111, reason: '', changedBy: "user"}]);
    } `

Comment: The problem here definitely isn't asynchronism. You're filter function is probably wrong, but no one can make any solid conclusions until you share some more data (`idleData`, `idle`).

Comment: @NickParsons yes im passing a number

Comment: idleData = `[     { id: 0, cost: 10, days: 10, comments: 'comment 1', reason: "reason 1", changedBy: "user1" },     { id: 1, cost: 20, days: 20, comments: 'comment 2', reason: "reason 2", changedBy: "user2" } ];`
idle = `0`  @code 

I also seen people use .reduce is that a route I should try ? Not sure how to use it in this situation ?

Comment: Thanks for the data. Would you mind editing your question with that?

Comment: @code i just edited my question

Comment: What is `setIdleData()` and where is `portCallVoyageId` coming from?

Comment: Are you using `key={idleData[n].id}` in a component? That's the issue. The `id` for a particular object should never change, no matter where in the array it is.

Comment: Is `days: item.day,` an on-purpose rename or a typo?

Comment: @JosephCantos I added an answer. Did you get a chance to look into that. Hope it will work as per your expectation.

Comment: Have you tried any of the suggested solutions? Is there a useful solution or a solution that you can mark as accepted?

Answer (score 0):

Just tested your code and I think it works fine and the possible problem is in the `idle` variable.

I slightly rewrote the source code.

```js
const idleData = [
{id: 0,cost: 10,days: 10,comments: 'comment 1',reason: "reason 1",changedBy: "user1"}, 
{id: 1,cost: 20,days: 20,comments: 'comment 2',reason: "reason 2",changedBy: "user2"},
{id: 2,cost: 30,days: 30,comments: 'comment 3',reason: "reason 3",changedBy: "user3"},
{id: 3,cost: 40,days: 40,comments: 'comment 4',reason: "reason 4",changedBy: "user4"},
{id: 4,cost: 50,days: 50,comments: 'comment 5',reason: "reason 5",changedBy: "user5"},
];

//idle = 0; 

const removeData = (omitId) => {
  const del = idleData
    .filter(({ id }) => id !== omitId)
    .map((item, index) => ({ ...item, id: index }));

  console.log(del);
  // setIdleData(del);
};

  console.log(del);
  // setIdleData(del);
};

removeData(0);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height: 100%!important; top: 0}
```

Same result but without `.filter`

```js
const idleData = [
{id: 0,cost: 10,days: 10,comments: 'comment 1',reason: "reason 1",changedBy: "user1"}, 
{id: 1,cost: 20,days: 20,comments: 'comment 2',reason: "reason 2",changedBy: "user2"},
{id: 2,cost: 30,days: 30,comments: 'comment 3',reason: "reason 3",changedBy: "user3"},
{id: 3,cost: 40,days: 40,comments: 'comment 4',reason: "reason 4",changedBy: "user4"},
{id: 4,cost: 50,days: 50,comments: 'comment 5',reason: "reason 5",changedBy: "user5"},
];

//idle = 0; 

const removeData = (omitId) => {
  const del = idleData
    .flatMap((item, index) => (item.id !== omitId) 
      ? { ...item, id: index } 
      : []);

  console.log(del);
  // setIdleData(del);
};


removeData(0);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height: 100%!important; top: 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working like a champ! I am adding the code snippet below. Please let me know what challenges you are facing. I will modify that as per the input.

**Demo :**

```js
const idleData = [{
  id: 0,
  cost: 10,
  days: 10,
  comments: 'comment 1',
  reason: "reason 1",
  changedBy: "user1"
}, {
  id: 1,
  cost: 20,
  days: 20,
  comments: 'comment 2',
  reason: "reason 2",
  changedBy: "user2"
}];

 const removeData = (id) => {
   const del = idleData.filter(idle => id !== idle.id).map((item,index) => (
     {
       id: index, 
       days: item.day,
       comments: item.comments,
       cost: item.cost,
       reason: item.reason,
       portCallVoyageId: item.portCallVoyageId,
       changedBy: item.changedBy
     }
   ));
   console.log(del);
 }
 
 removeData(0);
```